# How to set values for the meta og tag before the page loads using javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook

Without using server side programming, could it be possible to set the meta tags data(i.e facebook og: tags) that could be scraped by facebook scraper.

Because my problem here is I had written a javascript to dynamically set the meta tag data but when I used to post it on the facebook, the facebook fetches the information from the meta tags which is not yet updated by the javascript code

(i.e because which executed on the browser end but whereas the facebook scraper obtains concern information from the server side).

Comment: No, Facebook scrapper, AFAIK, does not check for dynamically generated meta tags. This to prevent spam.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply @ Adam, Is there any other way to satisfy my need. I just want to make my dynamic web page get as post shared in FB by copy/pasting the URL in the post input given in FB. As soon as i paste the URL the FB is not picking up the title, description, and image appropriately. When i share that through the share button created from my web page created, it is working as intended and picking the information appropriately

Comment: If you don't want server side solution than remove php from tags. Because this doesn't have anything with php

Comment: this has been asked a lot of times already, please do some research before asking. there are many other threads about it, i just marked the first one as duplicate. it is not possible with javascript, you have to do it server side.

Comment: Thanq everyone for your reply . As this is my first question post i dont notice the above concerns. Further i would correct it. @mandza and  luschn